# Huge gap showing between intro photo and first text on mobiles

Tags: html, css

I am aware there is already the same question posed on SO, but the solution there didn't do anything for me, mostly because I don't have the photo in a header but rather as a background in a new section.

The gap is not showing on PC, only on mobile devices. The whole code is way too long, so I'll only provide the parts affecting these two elements.

```css
/*========== INTRO ==========*/
#intro {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: url(img/bg5.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
display: block;
vertical-align: bottom;
}

.intro__container{
  height: calc(100vh - var(--header-height));
  align-content: center;
}

/*========== ABOUT ==========*/
.about__data{
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.about__description{
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-3);
}

.about__img{
  width: 280px;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  justify-self: center;
}
```

```html
<!--========== INTRO ==========-->
<section class="intro" id="intro">
    <div class="intro__container bd-container bd-grid">
        <div class="intro__data">
        </div>  
    </div>
</section>

<!--========== ABOUT ==========-->
<section class="about section bd-container" id="about">
    <div class="about__container  bd-grid">
        <div class="about__data">
                        
            <h2 class="section-title about__initial">OPERA <br> Prosecco Bar</h2>
                        <p class="about__description">Ponorte sa s nami do histórie a nechajte sa rozmaznávať pravým talianskym proseccom, alebo si príďte vychutnať kráľovské raňajky. </p>
        </div>

        <img src="img/obrazok.jpg" alt="" class="about__img">
    </div>
</section>
```

[view on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaq2c.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing `height: calc(100vh - var(--header-height))` is what's causing it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).